# Complications trying to exclude a specific column from a Json object why writing an SQL query on snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and I am trying to write an SQL query to create a JSON object while excluding a specific column from the output

table: lex

| id | Amount | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 200 | accept |
| 001 | 100 | accept |
| 002 | 200 | accept |
| 002 | 100 | accept |
| 003 | 200 | accept |

my codes so far

```
With wt as (
    Select *
    FROM lex
),
-------Convert to JSON------
wt_json as (
    select id,
            ARRAY_AGG(object_construct_keep_null(*)) withdrawals
    from wt
    Group by id
)
select *  from wt_json
```

this produces an output similar to this

| id | withdrawals |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | [{id: 01, amount :200, status: accept},{id: 01, amount :100,status: accept}] |
| 02 | [{id: 02, amount :200, status: accept},{id: 02, amount :100,status: accept}] |
| 03 | [{id: 03, amount :200, status: accept}] |

However, I am trying to exclude the Id in the JSON object.

what I am trying to achieve

| id | withdrawals |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | [{ amount :200, status: accept},{ amount :100,status: accept}] |
| 02 | [{ amount :200, status: accept},{ amount :100,status: accept}] |
| 03 | [{ amount :200, status: accept}] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with [OBJECT_DELETE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_delete.html) is the id has to be the same case as the key, as JSON is case sensitive, and yet SQL is not, and thus by default it all becomes upper case, thus in my code below given I allow `id` to be non-qouted, it really is `'ID'` for the OBJECT_DELETE command.

thus:

```
WITH wt AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('001', 200, 'accept'),
        ('001', 100, 'accept'),
        ('002', 200, 'accept'),
        ('002', 100, 'accept'),
        ('003', 200, 'accept')
        v(id, amount, status)
)
SELECT w.id,
    ARRAY_AGG(object_construct_keep_null(*)) AS org_withdrawals,
    ARRAY_AGG(object_delete(object_construct_keep_null(*),'ID')) AS del_withdrawals,
    ARRAY_AGG(object_construct_keep_null('amount', w.amount, 'status', w.status)) AS add_withdrawals
FROM wt as w
GROUP BY 1;
```

| ID | ORG_WITHDRAWALS | DEL_WITHDRAWALS | ADD_WITHDRAWALS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | [ { "AMOUNT": 200, "ID": "001", "STATUS": "accept" }, { "AMOUNT": 100, "ID": "001", "STATUS": "accept" } ] | [ { "AMOUNT": 200, "STATUS": "accept" }, { "AMOUNT": 100, "STATUS": "accept" } ] | [ { "amount": 200, "status": "accept" }, { "amount": 100, "status": "accept" } ] |
| 003 | [ { "AMOUNT": 200, "ID": "003", "STATUS": "accept" } ] | [ { "AMOUNT": 200, "STATUS": "accept" } ] | [ { "amount": 200, "status": "accept" } ] |
| 002 | [ { "AMOUNT": 200, "ID": "002", "STATUS": "accept" }, { "AMOUNT": 100, "ID": "002", "STATUS": "accept" } ] | [ { "AMOUNT": 200, "STATUS": "accept" }, { "AMOUNT": 100, "STATUS": "accept" } ] | [ { "amount": 200, "status": "accept" }, { "amount": 100, "status": "accept" } ] |

If you want control of the case of your output object, I would go the [OBJECT_CONSTRUST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html) direction, as there you have independent control. But if you are concerned the table will change shape, OR there are many columns, the `* - ID` approach, might be the simplest, albeit less performant option.

Answer (score 1):

Using [OBJECT_DELETE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_delete.html):

> Returns an object containing the contents of the input (i.e.source) object with one or more keys removed.

```
With wt as (
    Select *
    FROM  lex
 ),
-------Convert to JSON------
wt_json as (
   select id,
       ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_DELETE(object_construct_keep_null(*), 'id')) withdrawals
   from wt
   Group by id
)
select *  from wt_json
```

Comment: thanks for the response but it didn't remove the id in the JSON object

Answer (score 1):

You are using * in the `object_construct_keep_null` function. This means the object is constructed from from all available columns. If you don't want this then instead specify each column that you do want, in the form `'key', value`. You can include the "id" column separately to achieve what you want:

```
WITH src AS (
    SELECT '01' AS "id", 200 AS "amount", 'accept' AS "status"
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '01' AS "id", 100 AS "amount", 'accept' AS "status"
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '02' AS "id", 200 AS "amount", 'accept' AS "status"
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '02' AS "id", 100 AS "amount", 'accept' AS "status"
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '03' AS "id", 200 AS "amount", 'accept' AS "status"
)
SELECT 
      "id"
    ,  array_agg(
          object_construct_keep_null(
                'amount', "amount", 
                'status', "status"
          )
       ) AS "withdrawals"
FROM src
GROUP BY "id"
```

Result:

```
id     withdrawals
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01  [  {    "amount": 200,    "status": "accept"  },  {    "amount": 100,    "status": "accept"  }]
02  [  {    "amount": 200,    "status": "accept"  },  {    "amount": 100,    "status": "accept"  }]
03  [  {    "amount": 200,    "status": "accept"  }]
```

Comment: thats for the response. this is doable, but if you have over 30 columns, listing them one by one is an over kill

Comment: If you had over 30 columns then it would have been good to mention that in your original question - my answer is based on the example you provided, which had two columns.

Comment: Also by using * you are assuming the schema of the source table will never change. If columns are added or removed from that table in future then the resulting json object schema will also change and you could end up with additional properties in your array without necessarily being aware of it. Using * with SELECT in production code is generally considered bad practice in SQL for the same reasons.